# Mojarra 2.2-snapshot and doctypes

Tags: java, html, jsf, mojarra

I've decided to try JSF 2.2 (or what we have of it so far), so I grabbed the latest snapshot build of Mojarra and set it up. Now I have a template that uses prettyphoto. It worked great on JSF 2.1, but the minute I changed to the latest mojarra build, the prettyphoto window wasn't showing. It drived me crazy for a couple of hours (I have 2 glassfish servers in my pc now, one with the latest mojarra, and one with the stable one). I got it to work after realising that the latest mojarra build was not ignoring the DOCTYPE of a template client that started with `<ui:composition>`.

To make my example more clear.. I have something like this:

> *JSF **MASTER TEMPLATE** WITH **DOCTYPE HTML** AND A FEW UI:INSERTS*

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
```

---

JSF REGULAR PAGE THAT IMPLEMENTS MASTER TEMPLATE WITH DOCTYPE COMPOSITION:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:jsf="http://java.sun.com/jsf"
                template="./WEB-INF/template/MASTERTEMPLATE.xhtml>


                  .....<ui:define /> etc etc....


</ui:composition>
```

When this later template client gets rendered to the browser, it is sent with the doctype composition.. I thought it was supposed to ignore everything outside ui:composition..
In the stable Mojarra build, the Composition DOCTYPE is ignore and it goes out as html...

I initially suspected this is a bug, but maybe it's on purpose? Though they should tell you that, I lost all day with this.

Comment: Rants about JSF 2.2 latest snapshot?

Comment: No man, how can I rant about a snapshot? Haha. Just wondering if this is a bug or expected behavior. If it's a bug I'll report it, I just wanted to check here first.

Comment: It would be better to report it and then guys will do its work.

Comment: Will do, I'll just let this question hang out here for a bit in case anyone knows the spec, and will delete once I file the report

Comment: I was scracthing my head for quite a while because of DOCTYPE being composition rather than html which caused some CSS issues for me. Finally figured out the order in which the DOCTYPEs are parsed for templates includes etc. And I wonder, what is the purpose of having  "DOCTYPE composition" if all it does is create such chaos... I think I will remove all of that from 'ui:composition' and make my life simpler

Answer (score -1):

i have this code

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"                
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        template="/template/template.xhtml">
```

if your template folder is in web-inf add this folder

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"                
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            template="/WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml">
```

Comment: This answer isn't making any sense. Have you read and understood the question? If so and you're confident that the answer is right, please edit your answer to elaborate in technical terms exactly *why* and *how* the problem is caused and how this answer solves it.